# how to set a property of another class in C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, console-application

i have the below snippet in a C# console application.

```
namespace backupSystemAdministration
{
    class backupSystem {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            backupSystemaccess obj = new backupSystemaccess();
            string input = filepath.Split(',')[0];
        }
        private static void addbackup(string line) {
            backupSystemaccess.wordval = line; //error
        }
    }
  public  class backupSystemaccess {
        public  static  string _word;
         public  static string wordval {
            get {
                return _word;
            }
            set {
                _word = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to set property of backupSystemaccess from the class backupSystem. getting error in the line **backupSystemaccess.wordval=line**

the property created is not listed. 
Attached the screen what im getting when accessing instance.
[image]
Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: backupSystemaccess = new backupSystemaccess();.. are you sure?

Comment: e@RNATeam. edited. still hv the issue

Comment: @user833985 make wordval property public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `wordval` need to be `public` also because `wordval` is static you should make field `_word` static too. Also based on [`Naming Guidelines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) it is better you rename `wordval` property to `Wordval`:

```
static string _word;

public static string Wordval
{
    get
    {
        return _word;
    }
    set
    {
        _word = value;
    }
}
```

Or you can use [`Auto-Implemented Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)  instead:

```
public static string Wordval { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `wordval` as `static` but `_word` isn't. I don't  know what you want to achieve but this *can* not work.

And

```
backupSystemaccess.wordval
```

says you don't wanted this as static.

On the other side I don't understand you line

```
backupSystemaccess = new backupSystemaccess();
```

Maybe you should try to get a better comprehension of OOP.

EDIT:
Now you are accessing the property `wordval` right but of course it can not set `_word` because it doesn't "know" what (and where in the memory) `_word` is because there can be as many `_word` as you want but the static method is unique.